# Join a "Teams meeting" on the Ubuntu [Microsoft Teams]

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft

I installed the Microsoft Teams software on my Ubuntu without any issue.

I received a meeting request on my Outlook email address containing a Teams Meeting Link.

When I click on that link it opens a new tab in my browser.
At the top of that new tab it says "Choose an application to open the msteams link".

Where do I find the newly installed Microsoft Teams software?

I tried in my Ubuntu terminal `whereis teams` and the output was `teams: /usr/bin/teams /usr/share/teams`.

What I did then was try both of those two but my Teams app didn't react at all.
No error either.

Am I missing something obvious here?
I'm not used to these kind of stuffs on Ubuntu.

Comment: After installing did you log off and back on?

Comment: Before I installed I didn't register my outlook account on Microsoft Teams yet. After I installed Teams I signed in my outlook account on Microsoft Teams. However I didn't "sign out, then log in" after the installation. I will try this and let you know if it worked.

Comment: On the ubuntu app Teams I logged out, then logged in. It didn't solve my problem.